# How to fix this attribute object has no attribute error in django?

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django from

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

and I got an attribute error

`AttributeError: 'Question' object has no attribute 'question_text'`

as I typed

`Question.objects.all()`

the models.py is

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    # ... 
    def __str__(self):
    ¦   return self.question_text

 class Choice(models.Model):
   # ...
    def __str__(self):
    ¦   ¦ return self.choice_text
```

please help me to solve this issue. I coded the same as in Django API

Comment: Why have you removed the class body? We can't see if you have *actually* defined a question_text field.

Comment: not bro i haven't removed class body i have implement from django doc as i have mentioned in above

Comment: But you removed it from the code you've posted in this question. Don't do that. You've clearly made some kind of mistake but since you haven't shown the code we can't tell you what it is.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/

Comment: i have implemented as same as given link

Answer (score 2):

Either you haven't defined `question_text` in your models, or you might have misspelled it in the function.

```
from django.db import models
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
    ¦   return self.question_text

 class Choice(models.Model):
   # ...
    def __str__(self):
    ¦   ¦ return self.choice_text
```

After this, you can just makemigrations, and migrate, like this.

```
>>>>./manage.py makemigrations
>>>>./manage.py migrate
```

Comment: no i haven't mispelled it i checked it more than two times

Comment: The error is that the function isn't able to find a variable named called `question_text`. That's it.